# How to convert local variables to global in if statements

Tags: python

```
async def purchase(ctx, weapon, quantity):
    if weapon == "0":
        weapon_name = "soldier#"
    elif weapon == "1":
        weapon_name = "sniper#"
    elif weapon == "2":
        weapon_name = "demolitionist#"
    elif weapon == "3":
        weapon_name = "spy#"
    elif weapon == "4":
        weapon_name = "armored_vehicles#"
    elif weapon == "5":
        weapon_name = "tank#"
    elif weapon == "6":
        weapon_name = "transport_truck#"
    elif profileData["rank"] >= "30":
        if weapon == "7":
            weapon_name = "nuclear_missile#"
        elif profileData["rank"] >= "50":
            if weapon == "8":
                weapon_name = "thermonuclear_missile#"
```

So basically if the weapon id they input for the argument it equals as a string like `soldier#` which affects how many soldiers they have. I just want to know how to convert it to a global var

Comment: yea i think it is: async def purchase(ctx, weapon, quantity):

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: heres my code: https://hastebin.com/uqobegaxuq.py after i put the global var in and did %purchase 0 1, it didnt do anything

Comment: You cannot *"convert a local variable to a global variable"*. Furthermore, you shouldn't use global variables, especially if you are learning Python. You will just learn a bad practice. What is it actually that you want to achieve here?

Comment: if weapon = "0" then it'll create a new var that is weapon_name like soldier#, then it'll grab information from a json file..

Answer (score 1):

you must declare the variable before use it in `if Statements`

```
async def purchase(ctx, weapon, quantity):
    weapon_name = ""  # <= just add this ligne
    if weapon == "0":
        weapon_name = "soldier#"
    elif weapon == "1":
        weapon_name = "sniper#"
    elif weapon == "2":
        weapon_name = "demolitionist#"
    elif weapon == "3":
        weapon_name = "spy#"
    elif weapon == "4":
        weapon_name = "armored_vehicles#"
    elif weapon == "5":
        weapon_name = "tank#"
    elif weapon == "6":
        weapon_name = "transport_truck#"
    elif profileData["rank"] >= "30":
        if weapon == "7":
            weapon_name = "nuclear_missile#"
        elif profileData["rank"] >= "50":
            if weapon == "8":
                weapon_name = "thermonuclear_missile#"
```